# How to create a while loop with multiple answers?

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a program which requires an A, B, etc. answer. I am trying to create a while loop in order to make sure the answer is one of the possible letters. I tried testing it as I had problems with putting multiple variable answers in one while loop before.

Heres my test:

```
message = input("Input A or B: ")
while (message != "A") or (message != "B"):
    message = input("Input A or B: ")
```

I've tried these also:

```
while message != "A" or "B"

while message != ("A") or ("B")
```

All of this code just makes the while loop repeat forever, no matter what answer you give. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the "or" to an "and".

Surely it shouldn't work like that but it works so whatever.

Comment: Hint: draw a truth table, what are the values of (message != "A") and (message != "B") when message is "A", "B" or "C". Then you will see why your original expression didn't work.